# Force BERT transformer to use CUDA

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I want to force the Huggingface transformer (BERT) to make use of CUDA.
nvidia-smi showed that all my CPU cores were maxed out during the code execution, but my GPU was at 0% utilization. Unfortunately, I'm new to the Hugginface library as well as PyTorch and don't know where to place the CUDA attributes `device = cuda:0` or `.to(cuda:0)`.

The code below is basically a customized part from [german sentiment BERT working example](https://huggingface.co/oliverguhr/german-sentiment-bert)

```
class SentimentModel_t(pt.nn.Module):
      def __init__(self, model_name: str = "oliverguhr/german-sentiment-bert"):
           DEVICE = "cuda:0" if pt.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
           print(DEVICE)
           super(SentimentModel_t,self).__init__()

           self.model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name).to(DEVICE)
           self.tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(model_name)
    
        def predict_sentiment(self, texts: List[str])-> List[str]:
            texts = [self.clean_text(text) for text in texts]
            # Add special tokens takes care of adding [CLS], [SEP], <s>... tokens in the right way for each model.
            input_ids = self.tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(texts,padding=True, add_special_tokens=True, truncation=True, max_length=self.tokenizer.max_len_single_sentence)
            input_ids = pt.tensor(input_ids["input_ids"])
    
            with pt.no_grad():
                logits = self.model(input_ids)
    
            label_ids = pt.argmax(logits[0], axis=1)
    
            labels = [self.model.config.id2label[label_id] for label_id in label_ids.tolist()]
            return labels
```

EDIT: After applying the suggestions of @KonstantinosKokos (see edited code above) I got a

```
RuntimeError: Input, output and indices must be on the current device
```

pointing to

```
        with pt.no_grad():
           logits = self.model(input_ids)
```

The full error code can be obtained down below:

```
<ipython-input-15-b843edd87a1a> in predict_sentiment(self, texts)
     23 
     24         with pt.no_grad():
---> 25             logits = self.model(input_ids)
     26 
     27         label_ids = pt.argmax(logits[0], axis=1)

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1364         return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
   1365 
-> 1366         outputs = self.bert(
   1367             input_ids,
   1368             attention_mask=attention_mask,

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    859         head_mask = self.get_head_mask(head_mask, self.config.num_hidden_layers)
    860 
--> 861         embedding_output = self.embeddings(
    862             input_ids=input_ids, position_ids=position_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds
    863         )

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids, position_ids, inputs_embeds)
    196 
    197         if inputs_embeds is None:
--> 198             inputs_embeds = self.word_embeddings(input_ids)
    199         token_type_embeddings = self.token_type_embeddings(token_type_ids)
    200 

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py in forward(self, input)
    122 
    123     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 124         return F.embedding(
    125             input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
    126             self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)

~/PycharmProjects/Test_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1850         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1851         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1852     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1853 
   1854
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the entire class inherit `torch.nn.Module` like so:

```
class SentimentModel_t(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init___(...)
    super(SentimentModel_t, self).__init__()
    ...
```

Upon initializing your model you can then call `.to(device)` to cast it to the device of your choice, like so:

```
sentiment_model = SentimentModel_t(...)
sentiment_model.to('cuda')
```

The `.to()` recursively applies to all submodules of the class, `model` being one of them (hugging face model inherit `torch.nn.Module`, thus providing an implementation for `to()`).
Note that this makes choosing device in the `__init__()` redundant: its now an external context that you can switch to/from easily.

---

Alternatively, you can hardcode the device by casting the contained BERT model directly into cuda (less elegant):

```
class SentimentModel_t():
        def __init__(self, ...):
            DEVICE = "cuda:0" if pt.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
            print(DEVICE)

            self.model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name).to(DEVICE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast suggestion! I've tried both of your solutions, unfortunately, I get a 
"RuntimeError: Input, output and indices must be on the current device"
I've edited the original question

Comment: This is a different problem, unrelated to your original question. The error description is honestly quite telling: the device of your model and your input are not the same. You can resolve this by casting your input to the appropriate device, again using `to()` (it works for both `Tensor` and `Module` objects), i.e. `input_ids = input_ids.to("cuda")`

Comment: Yes it worked! Thanks, I've learned something today

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to the party. The python package that I wrote already uses your GPU. You can have a look at the [code to see how it was implemented](https://github.com/oliverguhr/german-sentiment-lib/blob/master/germansentiment/sentimentmodel.py)

Just install the package:

```
pip install germansentiment
```

and run the code:

```
from germansentiment import SentimentModel

model = SentimentModel()

texts = [
    "Mit keinem guten Ergebniss","Das ist gar nicht mal so gut",
    "Total awesome!","nicht so schlecht wie erwartet",
    "Der Test verlief positiv.","Sie fährt ein grünes Auto."]

result = model.predict_sentiment(texts)
print(result)
```

**Important:** If you write your own code to use the model, you need to run the preprocessing code as well. Otherwise the results can be off.